# Bad CRC32 in GZIP stream

Tags: silverlight-4.0, devforce

I am using DevForce 2010 and Silverlight 4.

When saving entities that contain large amount of binary data, I get this error:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

When debuging the application I see these errors:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

Bad CRC32 in GZIP stream.
```

I found this thread on Ideablades forum that discusses the problem: http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=3361&PN=1&title=bad-crc32-in-gzip-stream

Is this a problem on the server or client?

Is this a problem that has been resolved in any new version of DevForce 2010?

My server has 4 GB memory. Would increasing the memory resolve the problem?

Or what would be the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the OnEndpointCreated overrides on both client and server are where you should add the customization.  You can add the following to remove GZIP from the binding:

```
public override void OnEndpointCreated(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
{
    if (endpoint.Binding is CustomBinding)
    {
        var binding = endpoint.Binding as CustomBinding;
        var elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();

        // Swap out existing (GZIP) message encoding for binary
        var encoding = elements.Find<MessageEncodingBindingElement>();
        if (encoding != null)
        {
            elements.Remove(encoding);

            encoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            elements.Insert(0, encoding);
            endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
        }
    }
}
```

DevForce will find your classes if they're in an assembly probed on the client/server.

This will turn off compression for everything from your DevForce client to the EntityServer, so may be a bit heavy-handed.  You can turn on [IIS compression](http://blog.wassupy.com/2009/08/enabling-dynamic-http-compression-in.html) to compress data sent to the client to help.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I think I read somewhere that this bug is "open" at Ideablade. Is there a plan to correct this and when would a bug-fix be released?

Comment: Sorry, no plans to address this.  We might change the compression library used, but it won't necessarily address this problem.

Comment: One more question :) : Is this also a issue in DevForce 2012?

Comment: Yes.  DF2012 also uses the same GZIP encoder for the CustomBinding.

Answer (score 0):

There haven't been any changes to GZIP processing since the 6.1.7 release of DevForce 2010.  That thread still contains the best information of how to work around the problem:  1) modify the save logic or your entity definition to reduce the amount of data saved; 2) turn off use of GZIP; or 3) write a custom message encoder with another compression library.

Comment: Just to clarify: when I am saving entities, the client GZIP´s the data and sends it to the server. The server tries to decompress the data and ends up with OOM problems. One possible solution is simply to turn of GZIP on the client? How to I do that? Increasing memory will not help?

Comment: A second question: If I use InvokeServerMethodAsync to send data to the server, will this also go through a GZIP process?

Comment: DevForce is using a custom WCF message encoder to provide compression for all messages to and from the server.  This means that you can't turn off GZIP on the client without also turning it off at the server, and that InvokeServerMethod-related messages are also GZIP'ed.  If you turn off GZIP (by changing the CustomBinding) you can still have messages to the client compressed by using IIS compression.

Comment: I searched through my solution, but can not find any reference to CustomBinding. I am using a default setup of DevForce. Should I add this CustomBinding to my web.config?

Comment: If you're not familiar with WCF this gets a little tricky.  You can change the binding in either the .config file on both client and server, or in code, also on both client and server.  Take a look at some samples at the DevForce Resource Center to get a feel for what's involved - http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-samples-configure-deploy.  Once you decide on .config or code I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kim Johnson,

I have looked at the samples and I feel uncomfortable adding those config files and maybe breaking something that works fine today.

If I go the code-way, will I be ably to switch off GZIP and still retain the rest of the default settings for DevForce?

I guess the code below is what I should go for?

If I save these classes on the client and server, will DevForce automatically find these classes?

```
//Client

using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using IdeaBlade.Core.Wcf.Extensions;

public class ProxyEvents  : IdeaBlade.EntityModel.ServiceProxyEvents {

  public override void OnEndpointCreated(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint) {
    base.OnEndpointCreated(endpoint);
    // My client code turning GZIP off comes here?
  }
  public override void OnFactoryCreated(System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory factory) {
    base.OnFactoryCreated(factory);
  }
}

//Server
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using IdeaBlade.Core.Wcf.Extensions;

public class ServiceEvents : IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Server.ServiceHostEvents {

  public override void OnEndpointCreated(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint) {
    base.OnEndpointCreated(endpoint);
    // My server code turning GZIP off comes here?
  }
  public override void OnServiceHostCreated(System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost host) {
    base.OnServiceHostCreated(host);
  }
}
```