# Turning off GZIP in DevForce Config

Tags: silverlight, devforce

I have a Silverlight 5 app deployed in IIS 7 using data source extensions to connect to multiple databases.  We've been experiencing the "Bad CRC32 in GZIP stream" exception, so we decided to heed the advice to replace the GZIP binding with binary message binding and use IIS compression, which was given here:
[Bad CRC32 in GZIP stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868149/bad-crc32-in-gzip-stream)

But I must be missing something in my web.config.  When I replaced the gzipMessageEncoding node with binaryMessageEncoding, I started getting:

```
Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-gzip' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.
```

when my application was attempting to communicate with EntityService.svc/sl.

Here's my web.config, which I based on the sample web.config from the *IIS-Related Files* at http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-configuration-files.

```
  <ideablade.configuration version="6.00" xmlns="http://schemas.ideablade.com/2010/IdeaBladeConfig">
    <logging logFile="log/sl.xml" archiveLogs="true" />
    <objectServer>
      <serverSettings supportedClientApplicationType="Silverlight"/>
    </objectServer>
  </ideablade.configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />

    <services>
      <service name="EntityService">
        <endpoint address="sl" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinaryBindingHttp" contract="IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Server.IEntityServiceContract" />
      </service>
      <service name="IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Server.EntityServer">
        <endpoint address="sl" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinaryBindingHttp" contract="IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Server.IEntityServerContract" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="customBinaryBindingHttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" >
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="1200" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="error.htm" />
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities_1234" connectionString="XXX" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MyEntities_5678" connectionString="XXX" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The WCF binding information needs to be the same on both the client and server, so you also need to add or change the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig information on the Silverlight client.  There's a sample at http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-custom-client-servicemodel.

Comment: I was never able to figure out how to get the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig set correctly, so I ended up implementing ServiceProxyEvents and overriding OnEndpointCreated.